# IIS7 Application Pool Crash

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, application-pools

I am running IIS 7.0 on Windows server 2008 R2 and created 1 Application Pool per site and I have 1 site which is causing the application pool to stop. These are the following errors in the Event Viewer:

**This shows several times:**

A process serving application pool 'Pilot.Mobile.SyncV2' terminated unexpectedly. The process id was '3620'. The process exit code was '0x80131506'.

**Then I get this:**

Application pool 'Pilot.Mobile.SyncV2' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.

Two Things- How can I findout why this is crashing e.g. tools or scritps, also has anyone get any scripts I can run on a schedule task that will check the application pools and if 1 is down it will restart it and email me.

Answer (score 3):

You can find why it's crashing only by debugging the application; I'd start with the process exit code and look up what it means, and then enable sending ASP.NET error to clients in order to be able to see something in IE when the crash happens.

Other possible strategies: running the application pool with an attached debugger to see what's actually heppening, and/or modify the code to generate more detailed logs, include exception handlers, and so on.

If you are not one of the site developers, contact them; this is definitely an application issue, not a web server one.

---

To manage application pools from the command line, you can use the following commands:

```
appcmd start apppool /apppool.name: PoolName
appcmd stop apppool /apppool.name: PoolName
appcmd recycle apppool /apppool.name: PoolName
```

("Recycle" means "stop and restart").

Answer (score -1):

I recommend the command: `appcmd recycle apppool DefaultAppPool`